# Errores mapa con leaflet y google

Tags: autocompletar

Buenas, tengo un par de fallos que me traen de cabeza (contra la pared), a ver si me podeis echar una manilla…

El primero de ellos es que el autocompletar de google me funciona cuando le da la gana, hay calles que las coge perfectas y otras que me las pone en mitad de la nada o que devuelven “Spain” y peta todo xD En el select que se despliega salen bien las direcciones pero al pulsar una boom! peta…

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El otro error que también se puede ver en las fotos, es que el market no coincide con el inicio/fin de la ruta

No se que hacer ya por eso pregunto u.u el mapa esta hecho con leaflet con una capa de google y tira del autocomplete de google para poner las direcciones y sacar las rutas.
Es muchísimo código xD así que no se como ponerlo ni que poner porque no se por donde esta el fallo

Espero que me podáis ayudar un poquito, estoy muy atascada con esto.
Gracias

EDITO----
Creo que lo de los markers podría ser porque los creo simplemente en las coordenadas en las que se toca, sin mirar si es en mitad de una calle o del mar jeje pero no se bien como podría controlar que se creen en la calle, que es lo que controla la API para las rutas.

```js
if($scope.markers.length == 0){
 createOriginMarker(leafEvent.latlng.lat,leafEvent.latlng.lng);

 originLocation = {latitude:leafEvent.latlng.lat ,longitude:leafEvent.latlng.lng};
 reverseGeocode(originLocation, 0);
 fitMap();

}else if ($scope.markers.length == 1){        createDestMarker(leafEvent.latlng.lat,leafEvent.latlng.lng)

      destLocation = {latitude:leafEvent.latlng.lat,longitude:leafEvent.latlng.lng};
      reverseGeocode(destLocation, 1);
      fitMap();
      //Get int routes && save address
      getIntRoutes();
      //Finalizar listener con el ultimo marker
      clickMapEvent();
    }
```

Aquí es donde creo los markers

Y aqui es donde esta el evento del autocompletar, en el console log me da la misma direccion erronea que el resultado final

```js
$scope.$on('g-places-autocomplete:select', function (event, param, a, b) {
    console.log("format adress: " + param.formatted_address);
    $scope.searchForIntRoutes();
  });
```

```html
<div id="searchView" ng-if="searchViewControl">
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item mapInput">
            <img src="img/icon-start-48.png" class="icon placeholder-icon">
            <input g-places-autocomplete  name="origen" id="origen"  type="text"  placeholder="Origin" ng-model="data.origin" required>
          </div>

          <div class="item mapInput">
            <img src="img/icon-end-48.png" class="icon placeholder-icon">
            <input g-places-autocomplete name="destino" id="destino" type="text"  placeholder="Destination" ng-model="data.dest" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido Anntrick. Podrías trasladar a la pregunta el código que tienes y que crees que falla para ayudarte mejor? Un saludo.

Comment: Ya esta, he editado con lo que creo que da los errores =) gracias

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido corregir el error de los markers, resulta que la coordenada apunta a la esquina superior izquierda de la imagen, solo he tenido que ajustar eso en el css de leaflet.. y de paso le he agregado una función que redirige el marker a la calle mas cercana a donde se pulse.

Pero aun no consigo arreglar lo del autocompletar, por favor si alguien entiende de esto que me diga que puede ser =(

Gracias